# Difference between Baby Rudin 3.22 and 2.30

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having a bit of difficulty telling the difference between exercise 3.22 and 2.30 in Baby Rudin.

Exercise 2.30: If $R^k$ = $\cup_1^\infty F_n$, where each $F_n$ is a closed subset of $R^k$, then at least one $F_n$ has a non-empty interior.

Equivalent Statement: If $G_n$ is a dense open subset of $R^k$, for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...,$ then $\cap_1^\infty G_n$ is not empty (in fact, it is dense in $R^k$).

(This is a special case of Baire's theorem; see Exercise 22, Chapter 3, for the general case.)

Exercise 3.22: Suppose $X$ is a nonempty complete metric space and {$G_n$} is a sequence of dense open subsets of X. Prove Baire's theorem, namely, that $\cap_1^\infty G_n$ is not empty. (In fact, it is dense in $X$.)

I can tell that 3.22 adds the "nonempty, complete metric space" and that $\{G_n\}$ is a sequence of dense open subsets of X part in the theorem. But I'm wondering if the proof of the two is very different? For example, my proof for 2.30 was (for the equivalent statement):

1. Take any open neighborhood $N \subset R^k$ and take $N\cap G_1$, which is nonempty ($G_1$  is dense) and open (finite intersection of open sets)
2. Take a open set $V_1$ such that $\overline{V_1} \subset N\cap G_1$ (where $\overline{V_1}$ is closure of $V_1$) Note that $\overline{V_1}$ is compact
3. Take an open set $V_2$ such that $\overline{V_2} \subset V_1\cap G_2$. Note that $\overline{V_2} \subset \overline{V_1}$
4. Continue in this manner so we get $\overline{V_1} \supset \overline{V_2} \supset \cdots \supset \overline{V_n} \supset \cdots$, which is a sequence of  nested nonempty compact sets. So $x \in V_n$ means that $x \in N\cap G_n$ for all $n$ and so $\cap_1^\infty G_n$ is nonempty, as desired. (Denseness in $R^k$ is achieved because $\cap_1^\infty G_n$ intersects any open neighborhood $N \subset R^k$ at a nonempty intersection, and this is def. of being dense.)

Does this proof work for 3.22?

EDIT: I feel like I should be using the completeness of the metric space and the fact that $\{G_n\}$ is a sequence somewhere, but I'm not sure how. Can I just take $\{V_n\}$ to be Cauchy and so lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ diam $V_n$ = 0 and so $\cap_1^{\infty} \overline{V_n}$ contains one point.

But doesn't this just conclude more specifically that $\cap_1^{\infty} \overline{V_n} \subset \cap_1^{\infty} \overline{G_n}$ is nonempty? Is it necessary to include this statement?

Comment: In step 2, how do we know that $\overline{V_1}$ is compact?

Comment: In the situation of 3.22, it can be that no compact set has nonempty interior. The proof is similar to the case of a locally compact space (which, since you didn't use any specific properties of $\mathbb{R}^k$, you have effectively proved there), but instead of Cantor's intersection theorem, you must use completeness (and to do that, let the diameters of the $V_n$ shrink to $0$).

Comment: It's bounded by $N$ and is closed by definition of closure.

Comment: You never specified explicitly that $N$ should be bounded, so we can't conclude that $\overline{V}_1$ is compact. Add a remark to that effect and your argument works.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't quite understand your comment. What is a "locally compact space" and why must I use completeness? Also, does my edit work if I used completeness?

Comment: @DanielFischer Doesn't $N \subset R^k$ mean $N$ is bounded?

Comment: @MessyTiger : $R^k \subset R^k$ and $R^k$ is not bounded.

Comment: As an old Bourbakist, I say a locally compact space is a Hausdorff space in which every point has a compact neighbourhood. Rudin would say "has a neighbourhood with compact closure" since Rudin requires neighbourhoods to be open. If we drop the Hausdorffness condition, things become more difficult since then having a quasicompact neighbourhood doesn't imply having a neighbourhood basis consisting of quasicompact sets, and so there are two distinct concepts of local quasicompactness in the non-Hausdorff case.

Comment: Anyway, you must use completeness since the premise is just that we have a complete metric space, and the conclusion need not hold if the space is incomplete (e.g. $X = \mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean metric).

Comment: @DanielFischer So to use completeness, as you said in your comment above, I can just state in my proof that we let the diameters of $V_n$ shrink of 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$? And this is allowed because we can take $V_n$ to be a Cauchy sequence and all Cauchy sequences in a complete metric space converge? Is that reasoning correct on why we can let diam $V_n \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: We can let the diameters shrink to $0$ in any case. The point is that when we do that, the sequence of centres of the balls is a Cauchy sequence. Now, since the space is complete, this sequence converges to $y$, say. Then show that $y$ lies in the intersection of all $\overline{V}_n$.